# How to remove remove windows boot manager

Tags: boot, partitioning

I recently had a problem with my windows laptop and I decided to install Ubuntu. During the installation I selected C drive of my PC for Ubuntu to install ( earlier it was having windows OS) without any partitioning.I was able successfully install Ubuntu. Now While booting i see windows boot manager along with Ubuntu. How do I remove this windows boot manager? I am new to this Ubuntu platform.

I ran the sudo efibootmgr as suggested and got this output

```
checkmate@checkmate-LENOVO-IdeaPad-Z585:~$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000,0007,000B,0016,0004,0019
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System
Boot0002* ubuntu
Boot0004* PCI LAN: EFI Network (IPv6)
Boot0005  Setup
Boot0006  Boot Menu
Boot0007* ATAPI CD: MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8D1
Boot000B* ATA HDD0: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
Boot0016* PCI LAN: EFI Network (IPv4)
Boot0019* Lenovo Recovery System
```

Comment: Boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo efibootmgr` terminal command.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi and you may want to also remove /EFI/Microsoft folder from ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: Please also add output of `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove Windows Boot Manager by running in terminal

```
sudo efibootmgr -Bb 0000
```

Comment: That doesn't rectify the issue. It is still being displayed there. Moreover I am also seeing a  momentary message that states "dev/sda5 clean ..... blocks". The dev/sda5 is where is chose to install Ubuntu. It previously contained Windows OS.

Comment: Where "there" it is displayed? Is it in grub menu or where? Can you explain it in your question? Did you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: The command Pilot6 specified should work for you. If it doesn't, then chances are your firmware is adding the entry back. If the file `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` is present in Ubuntu, then deleting it might enable Pilot6's command to work. If that doesn't help, then just accept that the entry will be there; it should do no harm if the Windows boot loader (`bootmgfw.efi`) is not present on the hard disk.